# Are the preprocessor commands in C counted as tokens?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, token

I was reading about tokens and counting the number of tokens in  a program.

Previously I read somewhere that preprocessor commands are not counted as tokens.
But when I read about tokens on [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-tokens/) it is given in section "special symbols":

> pre processor(#): The preprocessor is a macro processor that is used automatically by the compiler to transform your program before actual compilation.

So I am confused that  in a program,  if we write `#define` will it be a token?

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#define max 100 
int main() 
{ 
    printf("max is %d", max); 
    return 0; 
}
```

How many tokens are in this example.?

Comment: There's no such thing as c/c++ language.

Comment: What do you mean _valid token_? A _keyword_?

Comment: The geeks for geeks article is full of dubious explanations. I would ignore the article. That last time I looked at C++ syntax preprocessor tokens and tokens were different things, and a preprocessor token would **not** count as a token.

Comment: I mean will it be a  simply count  as a token or not?  please specify how many tokens are in that program so i can get better knowledge

Comment: @Amit As mentioned define _valid token_ first please.

Comment: The number of tokens in that program is impssible to say because you have to count all the tokens in `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: When the preprocessor runs you will wind up with a file that contains the complete contents of stdio.h and everything stdio.h includes. That is a lot of tokens.

Comment: @john  do we count  #include and  #define as a token

Comment: @Amit No, they are preprocessor directives. they're not even preprocessor tokens, IIRC.

Comment: I count 16 tokens.

Comment: @john The '#' and the 'include' are each a preprocessor token.  The only aspects of the language that are _not_ defined in terms of some kind of token are comments, backslash-newline, and trigraphs.

Comment: Thank you.. So if i remove the first two lines there are only 16tokens   am i right?

Comment: @zwol I stand corrected.

Comment: @Nusakan: MS is certainly a very bad resource for the **C** standard. They don't even support the 19 year old C99.

Answer (score 8):

The linked article is full of basic errors, and should not be relied upon.

The process of parsing C or C++ is defined as a series of transformations:<sup>1</sup>

1. Backslash-newline is replaced with nothing whatsoever -- not even a space.
2. Comments are removed and replaced with a single space each.
3. The surviving text is converted into a series of *preprocessing* tokens.  These are less specific than the tokens used by the language proper: for instance, the keyword `if` is an IF token to the language proper, but just an IDENT token to the preprocessor.
4. Preprocessing directives are executed and macros are expanded.
5. Each preprocessing token is converted into a token.
6. the stream of tokens is parsed into an abstract syntax tree, and the rest of the compiler takes it from there.

Your example program

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#define max 100 
int main() 
{ 
    printf("max is %d", max); 
    return 0; 
}
```

will, after transformation 3, be this series of 23 preprocessing tokens:

```
PUNCT:# IDENT:include INCLUDE-ARG:<stdio.h>
PUNCT:# IDENT:define IDENT:max PP-NUMBER:100
IDENT:int IDENT:main PUNCT:( PUNCT:)
PUNCT:{
IDENT:printf PUNCT:( STRING:"max is %d" PUNCT:, IDENT:max PUNCT:) PUNCT:;
IDENT:return PP-NUMBER:0 PUNCT:;
PUNCT:}
```

The directives are still present at this stage.  Please notice that `#include` and `#define` are each *two* tokens: the `#` and the directive name are separate.  Some people like to write complex `#if` nests with the hashmarks all in column 1 but the directive names indented.

After transformation 5, though, the directives are gone and we have this series of 16+n tokens:

```
[ ... some large volume of tokens produced from the contents of stdio.h ... ]
INT IDENT:main LPAREN RPAREN
LBRACE
IDENT:printf LPAREN STRING:"max is %d" COMMA DECIMAL-INTEGER:100 RPAREN SEMICOLON
RETURN OCTAL-INTEGER:0 SEMICOLON
RBRACE
```

where 'n' is however many tokens came from stdio.h.

Preprocessing directives (`#include`, `#define`, `#if`, etc.) *are* always removed from the token stream and perhaps replaced with something else, so you will never have tokens after transformation 6 that directly result from the text of a directive line.  But you will usually have tokens that result from the *effects* of each directive, such as the contents of `stdio.h`, and `DECIMAL-INTEGER:100` replacing `IDENT:max`.

Finally, C and C++ do this series of operations *almost*, but not quite, the same, and the specifications are formally independent.  You can usually rely on preprocessing operations to behave the same in both languages, as long as you're only doing simple things with the preprocessor, which is best practice nowadays anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup> You will sometimes see people talking about *translation phases*, which are the way the C and C++ standards officially describe this series of operations.  My list is *not* the list of translation phases; it includes separate bullet points for some things that are grouped as a single phase by the standards, and leaves out several steps that aren't relevant to this discussion.