# If Enums are compiled time, then how #define with Enums work?

Tags: c, enums

According to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677148/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-consider-enum-values-as-equal), Pre-processors are evaluated first and then enums are processed. I checked this and true!

I have an Enum `eTypes`

```
typedef enum
{
   eTYPE_1 = 0u,
   eTYPE_2,
   eTYPE_3,
   eTYPE_MAX
} eTypes;
```

Then I define a size as

`#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE   (2 * eTYPE_MAX)`

And declare array as `U8 TestArray[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]`

According to linked question, while processing `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE`, compiler doesn't know `eTypes`. Then how `TestArray` gets correct size. I see TestArray of 6 bytes.

Comment: Preprocessor replaces macros in source code. You have actually declared the array as `U8 TestArray[ (2 * eTYPE_MAX) ];`.

Comment: The preprocessor turns the line into `U8 TestArray[(2 * eTYPE_MAX)]` and that's fine for the compiler

Comment: You are mixing apples and oranges. What the other Q&A says is that you can't get anything meaningful out of `#if eTYPE_MAX == 4`

Comment: How do you check the array size? With your example, `eTYPE_MAX` should get the value `3`, so the array should have a size of `6`.

Comment: @Bodo I was off by 1 :-) In code, it was correct... Modified the question.

Comment: If you want to know what the preprocessor does run: `gcc -E input-file` or equivalent for your compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preprocessor does a simple text replacement(*) from

```c
U8 TestArray[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]
```

to

```c
U8 TestArray[(2 * eTYPE_MAX)]
```

which will then be processed by the compiler. The compiler will calculate the constant value `2 * eTYPE_MAX` at compile time which results in `2 * 3 = 6`.

(*) To be more correct, the processing of the source code by preprocessor and compiler is a bit more complicated. The preprocessor processes tokens, not random parts of the input text. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52468676/10622916.

The main point regarding to the question is that the preprocessor doesn't care if `eTYPE_MAX` in the replacement text is an `enum` value, not even if the replacement is valid C code at all.

Comment: FYI, preprocessing operates on preprocessor tokens, not text. (A consequence of this is that macro substitution will not form new preprocessor tokens. With text replacement, two pieces of text next to each other could be reinterpreted as a different C token. With token replacement, they cannot.)

Answer (score 1):

> According to linked question, while processing `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE`,
>   compiler doesn't know `eTypes`. Then how `TestArray` gets correct size. I
>   see TestArray of 8 bytes.

Um, no.  You seem to be misreading this remark from [the accepted answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34677270/2402272):

> The preprocessor runs before the compiler knows anything about your
>   `enum`. The preprocessor only knows about macros (`#define`).

*The preprocessor* doesn't recognize the enumeration constants as different from any other identifier, but of course *the compiler* knows about them as long as the enum declaration is in scope.  Do not be confused by the fact that in practice, both of these tools typically reside and operate within the same program.

There is a separate question of whether an expression involving enum constants is considered a compile-time constant, but the standard answers that clearly:

> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only
>   have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
>   character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
>   constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating constants that are the
>   immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant
>   expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types,
>   except as part of an operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

(C2011, 6.6/6)

An "integer constant expression" is the kind required for the dimension of an ordinary array (as opposed to a variable-length one).